# Webcam not recoginized on 18.04

Tags: webcam

Webcam is a SJCam SJ4000 and worked fine on Artful.
It is recognized as mass storage when that option is chosen on the cam.
I get nothing when trying cam mode on Bionic.

`lsusb` output without cam plugged in

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a81:0101 Chesen Electronics Corp. Keyboard  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`lsusb` output with cam plugged in

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a81:0101 Chesen Electronics Corp. Keyboard  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0603:8612 Novatek Microelectronics Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0603:8612 Novatek Microelectronics Corp.` must be the cam.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The chipset for the device id `0603:8612`  is a Novatek NT96650. Can you post the output of the command `dmesg | grep -i NT96650`? Thanks.

Comment: No output at all.

Comment: you may see the details by typing this instead..
having the same issue,myself, the camera was working but now its not. But works on other devices. ````
dmesg | grep -i 0603:8612 ````

Comment: dmesg | grep -i 0603:8612
[ 2109.819278] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device J1455  (0603:8612)
[ 2633.301734] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device J1455  (0603:8612)